# SAS Assign variable if it meets any of multiple string requirements

Tags: if-statement, find, sas

```
if find(upcase(owner,in('ADMIN'|'ASSOC'|'BANK'|'CHRIST'|'CHURCH'|'CITY'|)))
THEN NameFlag = 1;
ELSE NameFlag = 0;
IF NameFlag > 0 then NameExclusion=1;
else NameExclusion=0;
```

I want this if statement to search variable OWNER for any string featured in the in statement and assign a flag if it hits.
Ideally I'd like to point this string at a separate data-set that I can just update on the fly, but I'm not quite sure I know how to do that yet.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: A little more info on the second question, please

Comment: I wanted to have a separate reference dataset with all the possible name exclusions. Maybe access it within the datastep through something like an infile statement. Something of an excel equivalent of an index array.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
If upcase(owner) in ('ADMIN', 'ASSOC', 'BANK', 'CHRIST', 'CHURCH', 'CITY')
 Then NameFlag=1;
Else NameFlag=0;
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, the values you are searching for are substrings in the Owner variable, rather than the whole value.  If that's the case then you can use the regular expression function `prxmatch` to find the strings.  This enables multiple searches against a variable, something which you can't do with the `find` function.

I've started by assigning the search values to a macro variable, for later use.  I don't know why you have the NameExclusion variable in your code, as it takes exactly the same value as NameFlag

```
%let search_str = ADMIN|ASSOC|BANK|CHRIST|CHURCH|CITY;

data have;
input owner & $50.;
NameFlag = prxmatch("/\b(&search_str.)\b/",owner)>0; /*sets value to 1 if true, 0 if false */
datalines;
ADMIN CLERK
TEST VALUE
SOME BANK
THE CHURCH
CHURCHILL
INTERCITY
;
```

Comment: Could also specify `/i` for a case insensitive match, which seems to be the intent. Also, if the values are stored in a dataset, then DomPazz's approach can be used with `separated by '|'` to separate by pipes rather than commas.

Comment: This is pretty close to solving the first part, except I can't edit for instances where I want to add spaces to the string, for example = ' USA ' | 'CHURCH' |' CHRIST'... to avoid picking up 'SUSAN' or 'CHURCHILL' or 'CHRISTOPHER' instead only grabbing 'USA BANKERS' or 'New Church' or 'Temple of Christ'. Any thoughts?

Comment: I've updated my answer, adding `/b` before and after the search string.  This means that there has to be a word boundary before and after the words searched for, i.e. it will only pick up the exact word, not where it appears in a larger word.

Answer (score 1):

To make this dynamic, use a data set with the values.

```
data values;
informat value $24.;
input value $;
datalines;
ADMIN
ASSOC
BANK
CHRIST
CHURCH
CITY
;
run;

%put &values;

proc sql noprint;
select "'" || strip(value) || "'"
into :values separated by ','
from values;
quit;

data want;
set have;
If upcase(owner) in (&values)
 Then NameFlag=1;
Else NameFlag=0;
run;
```

Comment: Can you go into more detail on this? where to I enter my strings to search and where can i enter my variables?

Comment: Put them in a data set (I use VALUES with the column name VALUE).  There are many ways to create a data set.